# siunitx: how can I avoid adding decimal zeroes?

Tags: tables, siunitx

How can I format a table column with `siunitx`**without** adding additional zeroes after the decimal separator?

I'd like to see **5,2** in the output **instead of 5,200** (however: **0,246 shall still be displayed as 0,246** and e. g. **0,200 shall still be displayed as 0,200** if it is given like that in the source code), but I can not find the correction options (`siunitx`is too flexible - at least much more flexible then my brain ;-)).

*The package options in the preamble have to stay as they are, as this otherwise would affect other tables.*

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[round-mode=places, round-integer-to-decimal, round-precision=2,
    table-format = 1.2, 
    table-number-alignment=center,
    round-integer-to-decimal,
    output-decimal-marker={,}
    ]{siunitx} 

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage[tight]{units}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lllS[table-format=1.3, round-precision=3, table-comparator=true, round-integer-to-decimal=false]}
\toprule
Eigenschaft & Einheit & Spezifikation & {Wert}\\
\midrule
{\ce{Y2O3}} & {(\unit{\%})} & {4,95--5,35} & 5,2 \\
{\ce{Al2O3}} & {(\unit{\%})} & {0,15--0,35} & 0,246 \\
{\ce{SiO2}} & {(\unit{\%})} & {$<0,02$} & <0,002 \\
{\ce{Fe2O2}} & {(\unit{\%})} & {$<0,01$} & <0,002 \\
{\ce{Na2O}} & {(\unit{\%})} & {$<0,04$} & 0,007 \\
GV    & {(\unit{\%})} & {$<1,2$} & 0,42 \\
Spez. Obfl. & {(\unitfrac{m$^2$}{g})} & {5--9} & 6,9 \\
Partikelgröße & {(\unit{\AA})} & {k. A.} & 390 \
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does changing `round-precision=3` to `=1` have the desired effect?

Comment: @Seamus: no, `round-precision=1` rounds **all** values to 1 decimal, but I just don't want that decimals are added: 5,2 shall stay 5,2 but 0,246 shall also still be displayed as 0,246! So I "just" want all numbers be aligned with the ",". (I've edited the question to hopefully make it more clear)

Comment: So you just want to remove trailing zeros? I see. I hadn't understood.

Comment: I've been thinking about this. It looks like `siunitx` has options to add missing zeros, but not remove trailing ones. And then I realised why: the trailing zeros are important: they tell you something! 5.200 tells you more than 5.2 would: "5.200" tells you it is _closer_ to exactly 5.2 than "5.2" does. You don't want to throw away those trailing zeros unless they are somehow spurious accuracy. In which case, you should probably remove them from the input.

Comment: @Seamus: no, not exactly: Yes, I want no trailing zeroes, if they were not there from the beginning. **However, I don't want to remove them (if they were there before), I just don't want to add them!** The data are taken from the analysis certificate of a vendor and I want to display the numbers exactly as they were given, without adding or removing anything! (As you stated correctly, "5,200" does not mean the same as "5,2"

Comment: in that case, does `add-decimal-zero=false` fix things?

Comment: @Seamus: no, `
add-decimal-zero=false` does not change anything.

Comment: @Martin: You do know that you are abusing the rounding system, I hope. In general, I would not expect rounding to be on for an entire document as it implies that you are not _thinking_ about where to round. The rounding system is intended for cases where auto-generated data tables need unrealistic precision removing. Leaving rounding on 'all of the time' makes it quite likely data is being rounded when you have not first checked that this is scientifically correct.

Comment: (My point being that while `siunitx` provides various tools, it is intended to support good science.)

Comment: @Joseph Wright: thank you very much for your comment - during the discussion here this thought also occured to me and left me with a bad feeling. ;-( So which commands should I leave out of the general package options? (concerning your second comment: no need to justify! You are absolutely (W)right! and I clearly need to understand what siunitx does to avoid producing "data trash" - Handling my big data tables in the appendix however brought me close to despair and produced some quick&dirty solutions...)

Comment: I've posted some thoughts as http://www.texdev.net/2011/07/17/which-siunitx-options-to-set-globally/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you need is the `round-mode=off` switch. [*Addendum, Nov. 2021*: see the remark at the bottom of this answer for an explanation on how to get his answer to work if you're working with version 3.x of the `siunitx` package.] Here's your MWE, slightly reworked:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[round-mode=places, round-integer-to-decimal, round-precision=2,
    table-format = 1.2, 
    table-number-alignment=center,
    round-integer-to-decimal,
    output-decimal-marker={,}
    ]{siunitx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\sisetup{table-format=1.3, round-precision=3, table-comparator=true, round-integer-to-decimal=false}
\begin{tabular}{S[round-mode=places]S[round-mode=off]}
\toprule
{``Places''} & {``Off''}\\
\midrule
  5,2   &   5,2   \\
  0,246 &   0,246 \\
 <0,002 &  <0,002 \\
 <0,002 &  <0,002 \\
  0,007 &   0,007 \\
  0,42  &   0,42  \\
  6,9   &   6,9   \\
390     & 390     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, Nov. 2021: In version 3 of the `siunitx` package, the valid choices for the `round-mode` option are `none`, `places`, `figures`, and `uncertainty`. Obseve that `off` is no longer a valid choice. Thus, in order to get the code shown above to run under v3 of `siunitx`, one needs to replace `round-mode=off` with `round-mode=none`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

**round-mode=off** (to overwrite `round-mode=places` in the preamble)

```
\begin{tabular}{llcS[table-format=1.3, round-precision=3, table-comparator=true, round-integer-to-decimal=false, round-mode=off]}
```

Answer (score 2):

The option is `round-pad=false`. According to the new doc of siunitx:

> The option `round-integer-to-decimal = false` has been **removed**, and whilst there is not a direct replacement, users are likely to find that `round-pad = false` offers the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

The option I think you are looking for is `add-decimal-zero=false`.

Section 5.5 of the `siunitx` manual (Post-processing numbers) contains all the relevant information on the options for how to represent numbers.

Having actually tried this, it appears not to work. It's certainly what the option *should* do. But it doesn't appear to work...

Comment: thanks for your effort: I've finally found it (and Mico Loretan posted it): **round-mode=off** helps. :-)

Comment: @Martin also, I recomment replacing the `units` package and its commands with `siunitx`'s replacements. And your package options include the `round-integer-to-decimal` option twice.

Comment: thanks for your recommendations! I started with `units`and discovered `siunitx` later when things got more complicated... I plan to replace units, but as I have extensively used it in the whole document, this will be quite time consuming as I fear side effects..

Comment: `add-decimal-zero` is *not* the right option. As far as I can tell, it's solely about the implicit zero in `123.` (notice the decimal point).