# siunitx rounding, don't add decimals

Tags: siunitx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [siunitx: how can I avoid adding decimal zeroes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23193/siunitx-how-can-i-avoid-adding-decimal-zeroes)

I have been using `siunitx` for physics reports and for some time it have annoyed me that given the settings.

- `round-mode` = places
- `round-precision` = 5 (as an example)

Then if I type `\Si{14.2}{\kilo\gram}` it will add 0's. What I would like is to set a decent default in the preamble that I can use throughout the document, and if a number has less significant numbers, they will not be added.

Comment: see comments in [How can i avoid adding decimal zeroes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23193/siunitx-how-can-i-avoid-adding-decimal-zeroes)

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a dupe of the linked question. This one seems to be essentially a feature request to have a 'round to at most X digits' mode, which currently does not exist.

Comment: @JosephWright, yes, I did not reference it as a dupe, rather the discussion you had with the OP of the other thread was quite conclusive on the problem in this question. It provides knowledge of your decisions in the making of your package.

Comment: I see your point Joseph. I will remove the automatic round default from my preamble.

Comment: If a mod comes by this topic can be closed.